# Google Calendar API - sendUPdate not working to

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

Using Google App Script to create a Calendar event and having problems with the "sendUpdates" parameter to send email notifications on the creation of the calendar event.

According to the documentation here: [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#sendUpdates).

[image]

The **"sendUpdates"** parameter has to be included, so my code looks something like this:

```
function createEvent() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var start = getRelativeDate(1, 23);
  var end = getRelativeDate(1, 24);

  var event = {
    summary: 'Lunch Meeting',
    // location: 'The Deli',
    description: 'Testing.',
    start: {
      dateTime: start.toISOString()
      // dateTime: start
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: end.toISOString()
      // dateTime: end
    },
    attendees: [
      {email: 'SOMEONE@GMAIL.COM'},
    ],

    sendUpdates: 'all',
    sendNotifications: 'true',
  };

  event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);

}
```

However, upon running the above function, I don't see any email notification about the Calendar Event being created.

Has anyone faced similar issues and have found a resolution?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove sendNotifications as that is deprecated.  I wonder if using them both causes issues.

Comment: You will not see email sent in your gmail, the email is just sent. Do you check with one of your account for checking if notification is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `sendUpdates` parameter as an optional argument (`sendNotifications` is not necessary) of
the `Calendar.Events.insert`, not inside the body request:

```js
function createEvent() {
 const calendarId = 'primary';
 const start = getRelativeDate(1, 23);
 const end = getRelativeDate(1, 24);

 const event = {
   summary: 'Lunch Meeting',
   description: 'Testing.',
   start: {
     dateTime: start.toISOString()
   },
   end: {
     dateTime: end.toISOString()
   },
   attendees: [
     { email: 'attendee1@gmail.com' },
   ],
 };

 event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId, {
   sendUpdates: 'all'
 })
}
```

###### Documentation

- [`Events.insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)

Comment: Oh boy, did not notice that! Thanks!